# Get the results of 2 Observables but after treating the result of the first one

Tags: angular, rxjs

As you can see below, I have 2 *Observable* with one common part

```
switchMap(({id: siteId}) => ...)
```

Would it be possible to combine those 2 *Observable* so I could use the result of the second *Observable* in the *subscribe* part (of the first one) ?

I know it's possible to have the results of both *Observable* and treat them at the same time with a *forkJoin* but in this case, I need in the end the **routineFullInformation** variable (1st *Observable*) and the **measureFullInfo** variable (2nd *Observable*).

In other words,

```js
this.subs.push(
            this.siteService.selectedSite().pipe(
                switchMap(({ id: siteId }) => this.walkthroughService.getRoutineForSite(siteId)),
                onErrorResumeNext(of(EMPTY_ROUTINE)),
                map(routine => {
                    this.routine = routine;
                    return WalkthroughService.routineToRoutineItemsPerRoomPerCategory(routine);
                })
            ).subscribe(routineFullInformation => {
                this.routineId = routineFullInformation.id;
                this.roomsMasterList = routineFullInformation.rooms;
                this.roomsMasterData = _.keyBy(routineFullInformation.rooms, 'id');
                this.categoriesMasterList = routineFullInformation.categories;
                this.categoriesMasterData = _.keyBy(routineFullInformation.categories, 'id');
                this.perRoomPerCategory = routineFullInformation.perRoomPerCategory;
                this.initializeForm();
            })
        );
```

```js
this.subs.push(
            this.siteService.selectedSite().pipe(
                switchMap(({ id: siteId }) => this.splunkService.getMeasures(siteId))
            ).subscribe( measureFullInfo => {
                console.log(measureFullInfo);
            })
        );
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: how do you want to combine ? not very clear. What's wrong with forkjoin these two

Comment: That is possible although we would need to know how those to are timed or if they are depend on each other. 
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree
could be helpfull for you

Comment: @FanCheung My bad. My question would be more something like this : where exactly could I forkJoin so that I can use the result of the second Observable in the subscribe part of the first Observable ?

Comment: how about forkJoin after the first `map(routine...`? you can pipe inside the argument of forkjoin if so desired

Comment: @RonaldHund so far I have something like this
[screenshot of a portion of the code](https://ibb.co/cQ25MLX) 

The console.log I do afterwards tells me it's an Observable so I still have to subscribe to get the actual results (which isn't ideal : I mean subscribe inside of subscribe)

Comment: @DatNguyen i meant something like 
...
pipe(
...
map(...)
forkJoin(this.siteService.selectedSite().pipe(...)) but that is basicalli what Fan suggested jsut in another order.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
    const obs1=this.siteService.selectedSite().pipe(
                    switchMap(({ id: siteId }) => this.walkthroughService.getRoutineForSite(siteId)),
                    onErrorResumeNext(of(EMPTY_ROUTINE)),
                    map(routine => {
                        this.routine = routine;
                        return WalkthroughService.routineToRoutineItemsPerRoomPerCategory(routine);
                    })
     const obs2=this.siteService.selectedSite().pipe(
                    switchMap(({ id: siteId }) => this.splunkService.getMeasures(siteId))
                )

forkJoin(obs1,obs2).subscribe(([routineFullInformation ,measureFullInfo])=>.....)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work :( I even added a console.log inside the subscribe to be sure it would go through but there's nothing in the console.




Edit : in the end, forkJoin wasn't the operator to use. With a combineLatest, your solution worked :)

Comment: (In case you don't see the edit) combineLatest is to use instead of forkJoin :)

Comment: weird. in your case forkjoin should just work the same as combinelatest. You can also try zip